# Group into time intervals postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a following selection:

```
|date_begin_sale|sale_id|count_offers|
|------------------|-------|-----|
|2021-03-01 05:05:00|84372|48|
|2021-03-01 05:10:00|84112|81|
|2021-03-01 05:20:00|84135|27|
|2021-03-01 05:20:00|83107|16|
|2021-03-01 05:30:00|83745|0|
|2021-03-01 05:30:00|82822|44|
|2021-03-01 05:35:00|84428|101|
|2021-03-01 05:40:00|83108|20|
|2021-03-01 05:50:00|83187|13|
|2021-03-01 05:55:00|84794|38|
|2021-03-01 06:05:00|84806|119|
|2021-03-01 06:05:00|83453|35|
|2021-03-01 06:10:00|83205|121|
|2021-03-01 06:15:00|84815|39|
|2021-03-01 06:30:00|82853|36|
|2021-03-01 06:30:00|84103|25|
|2021-03-01 06:35:00|83458|116|
|2021-03-01 06:55:00|83515|31|
|2021-03-01 07:00:00|84342|0|
|2021-03-01 07:00:00|83547|63|
```

I want to group them in such a way where timestamp can be grouped in 30 minute intervals, so I get this:

```
|date|interval|count(sale_id)|count_offers|
|-------|-----------|-------|-----|
|2021-03-01 | 05:00 - 05:30|4|172|
|2021-03-01 | 05:30 - 06:00|6|216|
|2021-03-01 | 06:00 - 06:30|4|314|
|2021-03-01 | 06:30 - 07:00|6|271|
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d8f82c03f53b93914a851361158152c)

```
SELECT
    start::date as date,                                           -- 5
    start::time || ' - ' || start::time + interval '30 minutes' as interval    -- 6
    count as count_sale_id,
    sum as count_offers
FROM (
    SELECT
        date_trunc('hour', date_begin_sale) +                      -- 1
            CASE WHEN date_part('minute', date_begin_sale) >= 30   -- 2
                 THEN interval '30 minutes'
            ELSE interval '0 minutes' END as start,
        COUNT(DISTINCT sale_id),                                   -- 4
        SUM(count_offers)
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY 1                                                     -- 3
) s
```

**First step** is to achieve the aggregation you are expecting:

1. Normalize your records to full hours.
2. Add `0 minutes`, if the original minute part is less than `30`, add `30 minutes` otherwise. This creates only records with hh:00 or hh:30.
3. These values can be used for grouping.
4. Do the aggregations you want: `COUNT(DISTINCT)` counts the distinct `sale_id` values and `SUM` adds all `offers` values

**Second step** is to generate the output format you're expecting:

5. The date is straight-forward: Simply cast the timestamp into date
6. To generate your interval, you have to cast the timestamp into the time part twice: Once for the start and once for adding 30 minutes as end value. These values can be concatenated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a thorough explanation.